# Custom order of x axis in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have these labels for axis X:

1..2..3..4..5..6..etc

But I need the custom order:

3..2..5..1..6..4..etc

Even if I give the array in such custom order to d3, it automatically orders it like in the first example.

I'm using `nv.models.lineChart()`.

The exact dump of my values:

`[{"values":[{"label":18,"value":12},{"label":19,"value":412},{"label":20,"value":441},{"label":21,"value":920},{"label":22,"value":944},{"label":23,"value":144},{"label":0,"value":0},{"label":1,"value":18},{"label":2,"value":0},{"label":3,"value":7},{"label":4,"value":4},{"label":5,"value":12},{"label":6,"value":0},{"label":7,"value":0},{"label":8,"value":0},{"label":9,"value":9},{"label":10,"value":9},{"label":11,"value":32},{"label":12,"value":27},{"label":13,"value":31},{"label":14,"value":0},{"label":15,"value":30},{"label":16,"value":3},{"label":17,"value":844}],"key":"Buyings count hourly","color":"#53d488"}]`

Comment: Try giving the numbers as strings, i.e. instead of 0 you would have "0" in your JSON.

Comment: I tried. No difference :(

Comment: Have you tried specifying an ordinal scale? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal